# How to identify slider when using multiple SlidesJS on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidesjs

I am using SlidesJS to show multiple sliders on one page. I'd like to use callbacks when a slider transitions to the next slide. How can I identify the slider instance that fired the event?

Here's the JS code I use to initalize SlidesJS:

```
$(function() {
  $('.slides').slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 528,
    callback: {
      loaded: function(number) {
        // Use your browser console to view log
        console.log('SlidesJS: Loaded with slide #' + number);

        // Show start slide in log
        $('#slidesjs-log .slidesjs-slide-number').text(number);
      },
      start: function(number) {
        // Use your browser console to view log
        console.log('SlidesJS: Start Animation on slide #' + number);
      },
      complete: function(number) {
        // Use your browser console to view log
        console.log('SlidesJS: Animation Complete. Current slide is #' + number);

        // Change slide number on animation complete
        $('.slidesjs-log .slidesjs-slide-number').text(number);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8w3abnk3/2/)

As you can see in the example, the `complete` callback updates **every** `.slidesjs-slide-number`. How can I update the slide number which belongs to the slider that fired the complete event, only?

Comment: Unfortunately, Slidesjs doesn't provide a second callback parameter and no other information than the slide number (from my tests anyways). Given that, I think the only way would be to copy/paste the `$.slidesjs()` and modify the callbacks for the slider you want to monitor. You could also look for other sliders libraries, such as bxSlider, that would allow you to get the `$sliderElement`returned in the callback.

Comment: Thanks @Marc-AntoineParent while searching for more information I also found slick http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ which does the job.